# HTTP method names must be tokens issue

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, rest-assured, spring-boot-test

I have a spring boot app, for which I have a bunch of integration tests written and they are using RestAssured to facilitate the REST layer interactions.
Here is the example of the RestAssured setup in my test:

```
@Before
public void restAssuredSetup() {
    RestAssured.port = getPort();
    RestAssured.baseURI = "http://localhost";
}
```

My tests were working fine, everything was green, but when I re-ran the entire test suite after some refactoring work, it started failing with:

```
2021-04-28 20:35:37.097  INFO [] 31959 --- [o-auto-1-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x83\uD821\uDD580xc70xbc0xe50xaf0x9e0xe70x890xaa0xec0xb90xad0xee0xbe0xe20x840x840xea0xba0x9d0xe30xbf0x98...]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:413)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:261)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
HTTP/1.1 400
```

Please note another peculiar aspect of this behavior: if I step into debug mode from my IDE, the test would pass more than 50% of the time.

I also ran my test suite from Maven, the same error is seen there.

I am clueless here.

Comment: Can you please add an overview of your used Spring Boot, REST Assured version? Please also add a sample test where this issue occurs. If you can quickly elaborate on what your refactoring work was about (updating dependencies? re-structure packages? new test setup?), it might help here.